# Is there UISwitch settings control in Android like iOS

Tags: android

I took a look at the preference activity that Android use for settings. i'm looking for something like UISwitch as shown in below image, does Android have one like this.

I can see the nearest control on Android preference settings is "list preference"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) and [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html) (one extends the other).

But those have a different default display widget then what you are looking for. However either could be used along with your own drawable resources to create the "switch" type control that you are after.

But by default no the system does not include a widget that serves this function and looks the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

No, In Android its called ToggleButton.
But still it can be developed by extending RadioButton placed in RadioGroup and giving its UI way you wanted.